# Android Connection handling on API 21+

Tags: android, service, connection, android-connectionservice

I am implementing a calling app and I want to do a self-managed ConnectionService. However, my application's min api is 21 whereas ConnectionService has a min of 23. I also noticed that the min api for setting the PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED is 26+.

I noticed that TelecomManager is available for 21+ but seems like a lot of functionality is still only available for 23+.

I need my app to be able to detect and work well with other calling apps... there must be a backwards compatible way of doing this. How have other people who have apps targeting 21 as the min api (which seems like a pretty common min) been able to manage calling/hold/incoming/outgoing/other calls from external apps gracefully with their own self-managed calling apps?

Comment: I'd target 23 and move on :-)

Comment: also have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/64425303/3496570